# XPath: how to get attribute of a node known by attribute value

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt-1.0

I have a collection ($targets) with id-s of columns (token). 
I loop through it and for each column's id (.) I want to get column with such id and then from this table-column node I want to get @val attribute:

```
<xsl:for-each select="exsl:node-set($targets)/token">
    <xsl:variable name="column" select="string(.)" />
    <xsl:value-of select="//aui:table-column[@id=$column]/@val"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

I know that I have a unique  with correct id, yet this XPath get's empty strings,

The collection and for-each work ok: if I replace

```
//aui:table-column[@id=$column]/@val
```

with

```
string(.)
```

the values of column id-s are ok like { col1, col2, .. }

Comment: Does your *stylesheet* declare the `aui` namespace?

Comment: yes, aui namespace is correctly declared

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Explanation - I've searched for table columns in the context of my for-each sampling which was made of nodes generated after tokenization, so I found nothing.

The code should include one auxiliary variable and be like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="docroot" select="/" />
<xsl:for-each select="exsl:node-set($targets)/token">
    <xsl:variable name="column" select="string(.)" />
    <xsl:value-of select="$docroot//aui:table-column[@id=$column]/@val"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `string(.)` is in the context of the `column` element node. It is in the condition for it. Put the token into a variable.

```
<xsl:for-each select="exsl:node-set($targets)/token">
    <xsl:variable name="token" select="normalize-space(.)"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="//column[@id=$token]/@val"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

`normalize-space()` cast a node into a string and normalizes the whitespaces.

Comment: Yes, I did it - still nothing (

Comment: This may be caused by extra whitespace in your column. You could try to use `<xsl:variable name="token" select=normalize-space(string(.))"/>` instead.

Comment: Updated it. string() is not needed if normalze-space() is used.

Comment: i`ll add it, but in my test conditions column names were 1-word-long and i output-ed them to make sure they were ok. there were no extra whitespaces.